# definition of the L-function $L(f, \chi, s): \mathbb{A}_K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, what is smoothness and what is $f$?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, class-field-theory, l-functions, adeles

To summarize the question I'm going to ask: for those who have studied L-functions and class field theory, I am confused about the definitions of some things and haven't found a good reference for them.  So I'm asking about what some things **should** mean. Let $K$ be a number field, and let $\mathbb A_K$ be the ring of adeles.  In my notes on class field theory, I recall a set $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb A_K)$, the set of $\mathbb{C}$-valued continuous functions on $\mathbb A_K$ which are "smooth" and of "compact support."  Being of compact support is straightforward: the closure of the set of $x \in \mathbb A_K$ which are not mapped to $0$ is compact.

"Smooth," however, can mean different things.  A function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ or $f: \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is called "smooth" if it is infinitely differentiable.  On the other hand, a function $f: K_v \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ ($K_v$ being some finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$) would be called smooth if it is locally constant (each point has a neighborhood on which the function is constant).

I am guessing a "smooth" function $f: \mathbb{A}_K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ on the adeles would be one of two things:

> (i) It is locally constant on the adeles.
>
> or (ii) The restriction of $f$ to each completion $K_v$ is smooth (which means locally constant or infinitely differentiable, depending on whether the place $v$ is finite or infinite)

Another thing: I remember us considering functions of the form $f_0 \otimes f_{\infty}: \mathbb{A}_K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $f_0$ is a function on the restricted direct product $\prod\limits_{v < \infty} K_v$ and $f_{\infty}$ is a function on $\prod\limits_{v \mid \infty} K_v$.  One then defines $f_0 \otimes f_{\infty}(x) := f_0(x) f_{\infty}(x)$.   I distinctly recall that one of the things was true:

> (i) every $f \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb A_K)$ is a finite sum of functions of the form $f_0 \otimes f$.
>
> or (ii) the set of such finite sums is dense in $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{A}_K)$.

So my question is: which one of the options (i), (ii) is the correct one?

Comment: (i) - finite sum of factorisable functions $\prod_v f_v$, with each $f_v$ being smooth (i.e. locally constant if $v$ is nonarchimedean and infinitely differentiable if $v$ is archimedean). Search for Bruhat-Schwartz functions - see e.g. Chapter 1 of Goldfeld-Hundley.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll check it out.  We were also told that "without loss of generality, we may assume that for a function $f_0 = \prod\limits_v f_v : v < \infty$, almost all of the $f_v$ were the characteristic function of $\mathcal O_v$." (specifically to prove that $L(f, \chi, s) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{I}_K} f(x)\chi(x)||x||^s d^{\ast}x$ is absolutely convergent for $Re(s) > 1$).  I would think that in order for $f_0(x)$ to be a finite product, almost all of the $f_v$ would just send $x$ to $1$ for all $x \in K_v$.  Would you happen to know what's going on here?

Comment: The adeles being a restricted product means that for almost every place $v$, $x_v$ lies in $\mathcal{O}_v$. This is why $f_v$ should be the characteristic function of $\mathcal{O}_v$ for almost every place $v$.